# How to select rows where the condition where all rows are being extracted for a given condition?

Tags: postgresql

I have this table

```
CREATE TABLE fruits 
(
    id SERIAL,
    name VARCHAR
);
```

with these entries

```
INSERT INTO fruits(name) 
VALUES('Orange');
INSERT INTO fruits(name) 
VALUES('Ananas');
INSERT INTO fruits(name) 
VALUES(null);
```

When I try to to select all rows that not equal to 'Ananas' by querying

```
select * 
from fruits 
where name <> 'Ananas'
```

I get these rows:

```
id  name
-----------
1   Orange
```

What I would have expected was this

```
id  name
-----------
1   Orange
3   null
```

How do I ensure that all rows that fulfills the condition gets selected?

Example in dbfiddle:
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=a963d39df0466701b0a96b20db8461e6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any "normal" comparison with `null` yields "unknown" which is treated as `false` in the context of the WHERE clause.

You need to use the null safe operator `is distinct from`:

```
select *
from fruits
where name is distinct from 'Ananas';
```

Alternatively you could convert NULL values to something different:

```
select *
from fruits
where coalesce(name, '') <> 'Ananas';
```

Comment: Does `is distinct from` work with any type?
`is 241` gives a syntax error

Comment: yes it works with any type, but `is 241` is invalid SQL. `some_column is distinct from 241` will work just fine.

Comment: if I will allow null to be selected I will need to change my `=` => `IS NOT DISTINCT FROM null´ and `<>` => `IS DISTINCT FROM null` ... Is there any drawbacks of using these two, beside the added complexity?